# Connect same machine to 2 openvpn servers

Tags: openvpn

I need to use 2 clients in order to tunnel traffic to 2 other machines.

I don't want my internet traffic tunneled but instead just to be able to communicate with the server over the tunnel.

Server A has ip 10.8.0.0 and server B has 10.7.0.0. If I connect to server A I'm able to connect normally and everything works but when I also connect server B I'm still able to connect but both VPNS are active and dead (no traffic goes through the tunnel).

I don't need the VPNs to be able to see each other, just the client machine to be able to use both tunnels.

Here are the configs:

Server A:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
#ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "remote-gateway placeholder"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
#duplicate-cn
#sndbuf 393216
#rcvbuf 393216
#push "sndbuf 393216"
#push "rcvbuf 393216"
user nobody
group nogroup
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo no
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

Server B:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
server 10.7.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.7.0.0 255.255.255.0"
#ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
#push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "remote-gateway placeholder"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
#duplicate-cn
#sndbuf 393216
#rcvbuf 393216
#push "sndbuf 393216"
#push "rcvbuf 393216"
user nobody
group nogroup
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo no
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

Client A:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote placeholder
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo no
route-nopull
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Client B:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote placeholder 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo no
route-nopull
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem apparently was the ip range... I changed 10.7.0.0 to 10.8.1.0 and everything worked almost directly...

Strange because I don't have any other network on that range.